# get value of array instead of index

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashmap

I am trying to retrieve an array and at the end I want to put all of them as a list into an hash, but I get only index and not the list of values.

```
$testArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"
foreach($item in $tempArray) {
    if ($item -notlike 123) {
        $arrayID = $testArray.Add($item);
    }
}

@{"mailboxes" = $arrayID};
```

As a result I would like to see values like

```
mailboxes {321, 453}
```

instead of index like below.

```
mailboxes 1
```

Comment: `@{"mailboxes" = $arrayID}` -> `@{"mailboxes" = $testArray}`

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList.Add()` method returns the index of the new array element, so you are just adding an integer to `$arrayID`. Instead:

```
$testArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$tempArray = "123", "321", "453"
foreach($item in $tempArray) {
    if ($item -notlike 123) {
        $testArray.Add($item);
    }
}
@{ "mailboxes" = $testArray};
```

returns:

```
mailboxes                      {321, 453}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the issue but still i get Output like:

0
1

Name                           Value                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                 
mailboxes                      {321, 453}

How to avoid that index part i.e 0 1

Comment: @rora Set $null = $testArray.Add($item) or just [void]$testArray.Add($item) to stop index from being returned

Comment: This did help me.

Answer (score 0):

if you end goal is to get this

```
mailboxes {321, 453}
```

then you could do this

```bsh
$OldArray = @("123", "321", "453")

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$NewArray = @()

foreach($item in $OldArray) {
    if ($item -ne 123) {
        $NewArray += item 
    }
}

@{"mailboxes" = $NewArray};
```

or just this...

```bsh
@{"mailboxes" =  @("123", "321", "453") | ? {$_ -ne 123}};
```

**side note:**
`@()` by default creates a `[system.array]` which are fixed in size. using `+=` on a `[system.array]` will result in a new array being created and the old array contents will need to be copied into it. 
`[System.Collections.ArrayList]` are dynamically size, they allow you to easily add new items.